# 403 being thrown when redirecting back to index page when trying to sign user in

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, openid-connect, http-status-code-403

We have been having this issue for quite a while now 4-6 weeks at this stage.
The issue happens when the user attempts to sign in they get a 403 error.
The issue is very intermittent as in it can happen once in every ten times.

It seems like the 403 is being thrown when, the user get redirected back to the home page from the sign in process.
We are using open id connect as the authentication method and the web app is hosted in Azure.

I’ve checked the code over and over again and can not find any discrepancies in the code. 
We also tried to capture the error using app insights but couldn’t find anything.

The web app is being hosted in an app service using kestrel.

Can anyone provide any insight into why something like this might be happening?

Comment: Assuming your application is ASP Core (with the question being tagged as C#), Is the application kestrel or IIS facing? It sounds like an IIS routing issue. Please update your question to provide more detail on the application. If you are using IIS, you can enable failed request logging and capture all 403 requests to get a detailed dump of why this is occurring. That being said, I guess you might have it hosted in App Services?

Comment: It’s definitely kestrel, it’s the default for .net core applications. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Well because its using app services you can still enable failed request tracing: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/01/27/enable-failed-reuqest-tracing-for-an-azure-app-service-web-app/ Another thing to try would be Application Insights as that will give you request failure details as well as a session log to see how the user got there. Maybe that will show a pattern?

Comment: We tried logging it in app insights but, no joy. As of right now I cannot get access to the failed request logs yet. When I do I’ll write an update on it.

Comment: Bit of an update. I got access to the failed request trace logs and the 403 wasn’t present in them either.

Comment: Sounds like this 403 isn't being sent by your server then. If you can replicate the issue for yourself, use a HTTP proxy (fiddler 4 etc) and see where the 403 is coming from. I assume with it being openid, it will be a 3rd party.

Comment: The error wasn’t captured by Fiddler either.

Comment: Then how are you replicating the issue? If fiddler isn't seeing it then you cant be either?

Comment: The only way that I can replicate it, is by going to the url and hoping that the 403 error occurs. It happens at least once in every ten attempts.

Comment: So are you saying that you have made a request and got a 403 response and fiddler is reporting a 200? Or are you saying you just cant replicate it?

Comment: I made the request. I got a 200 in Fiddler for it but, the server returned a 403. However, to add to that before the 200 response came in two 407 were thrown.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204336/discussion-between-kieran-devlin-and-albert).